# Why are the compilation errors when loading Scala build files?

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt 0.12.4 on Windows.

Firstly, I move into the project directory, that is `example` - a Scala project under sbt. When I run `sbt`, I get the following errors:

```
C:\programs\example>sbt
[info] Loading project definition from C:\programs\example\project\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/programs/example/project/project/}default-2ad7de...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#actions;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#io;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#collections;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#api;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logging;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#process;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compile;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#persist;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-rc1 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46 ...
[info] Resolving commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.12.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from C:\programs\example\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/programs/example/project/}default-116b7c...
[info] Resolving net.databinder#dispatch-http_2.9.2;0.8.8 ...
[info] Resolving net.databinder#dispatch-core_2.9.2;0.8.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.1.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4 ...
[info] Resolving net.databinder#dispatch-futures_2.9.2;0.8.8 ...
//some mor like the above
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to C:\programs\example\project\target\scala-2.9
.2\sbt-0.12\classes...
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:190: object Test is not a
 value
[error]     (argTask, currentProject, baseDirectory, handoutFiles, submitProject
Name, target, projectDetailsMap, compile in Test) map { (args, currentProject, b
asedir, filesFinder, submitProject, targetDir, detailsMap, _) =>
[error]
                                        ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:56: object Test is not a
value
[error]     (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test) <<= (scalaSource in Test)(Seq(_
)),
[error]                                    ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:265: object Test is not a
 value
[error]     (unmanagedSources in Test) <<= (unmanagedSources in Test, scalaSourc
e in Test, projectDetailsMap, currentProject, gradingTestPackages) map { (source
s, srcTestScalaDir, detailsMap, projectName, gradingSrcs) =>
[error]                          ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:265: reassignment to val
[error]     (unmanagedSources in Test) <<= (unmanagedSources in Test, scalaSourc
e in Test, projectDetailsMap, currentProject, gradingTestPackages) map { (source
s, srcTestScalaDir, detailsMap, projectName, gradingSrcs) =>
[error]                                ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:288: object Test is not a
value
[error]   val setTestPropertiesHook = (test in Test) <<= (test in Test).dependsO
n(setTestProperties)
[error]                                        ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:288: reassignment to val
[error]   val setTestPropertiesHook = (test in Test) <<= (test in Test).dependsO
n(setTestProperties)
[error]                                              ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:304: object Test is not a
 value
[error]       compile in Test,
[error]                  ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:512: object Test is not a
 value
[error]   val readTestCompileLog = (compile in Test) <<= (compile in Test) mapR
handleFailure(compileTestFailed)
[error]                                        ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:512: reassignment to val
[error]   val readTestCompileLog = (compile in Test) <<= (compile in Test) mapR
handleFailure(compileTestFailed)
[error]                                              ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:553: object Test is not a
value
[error]     (sourceDirectory in Test) <<= (sourceDirectory in (assignmentProject
, Test))
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:553: reassignment to val
[error]     (sourceDirectory in Test) <<= (sourceDirectory in (assignmentProject
, Test))
[error]                               ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:561: object Test is not a
 value
[error]     (unmanagedSources in Test) <<= (unmanagedSources in Test, scalaSourc
e in (assignmentProject, Test), gradingTestPackages in assignmentProject, gradeP
rojectDetails) map { (sources, testSrcScalaDir, gradingSrcs, project) =>
[error]                          ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:561: reassignment to val
[error]     (unmanagedSources in Test) <<= (unmanagedSources in Test, scalaSourc
e in (assignmentProject, Test), gradingTestPackages in assignmentProject, gradeP
rojectDetails) map { (sources, testSrcScalaDir, gradingSrcs, project) =>
[error]                                ^
[error] C:\programs\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala:570: object Test is not a
 value
[error]      compile in Test,
[error]                 ^
[error] 14 errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

**UPDATE**
When I press `l` at the commmand prompt, the error log is as follows:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\A\example\project\project
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]         removed:Set()
[debug]         added: Set()
[debug]         modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]         product: Set()
[debug]         binary dep: Set()
[debug]         external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[info] Loading project definition from C:\A\example\project
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]         removed:Set()
[debug]         added: Set(C:\A\example\project\Settings.scala, C:\A\example\pro
ject\StyleChecker.scala, C:\A\example\project\GradingFeedback.scala, C:\A\exampl
e\project\CourseraHttp.scala, C:\A\example\project\ProgFunBuild.scala, C:\A\exam
ple\project\ScalaTestRunner.scala, C:\A\example\project\RichJsValue.scala, C:\A\
example\project\RecordingLogger.scala)
[debug]         modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set(C:\A\example\project\Settings.
scala, C:\A\example\project\StyleChecker.scala, C:\A\example\project\GradingFeed
back.scala, C:\A\example\project\CourseraHttp.scala, C:\A\example\project\ProgFu
nBuild.scala, C:\A\example\project\ScalaTestRunner.scala, C:\A\example\project\R
ichJsValue.scala, C:\A\example\project\RecordingLogger.scala)
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]         product: Set()
[debug]         binary dep: Set()
[debug]         external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set(C:\A\example\project\Settings.sca
la, C:\A\example\project\StyleChecker.scala, C:\A\example\project\GradingFeedbac
k.scala, C:\A\example\project\CourseraHttp.scala, C:\A\example\project\ProgFunBu
ild.scala, C:\A\example\project\ScalaTestRunner.scala, C:\A\example\project\Rich
JsValue.scala, C:\A\example\project\RecordingLogger.scala)
[debug] Recompiling all 8 sources: invalidated sources (8) exceeded 50.0% of all
 sources
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to C:\A\example\project\target\scala-2.9.2\sbt-
0.12\classes...
[debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.9.2
[debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.9.2
[debug] Running cached compiler b206e9, interfacing (CompilerInterface) with Sca
la compiler version 2.9.2
[debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
[debug]         -deprecation
[debug]         -d
[debug]         C:\A\example\project\target\scala-2.9.2\sbt-0.12\classes
[debug]         -bootclasspath
[debug]         C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre6\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program File
s\Java\jre6\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files
\Java\jre6\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\classes;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.sbt\boot\scal
a-2.9.2\lib\scala-library.jar
[debug]         -classpath
[debug]         C:\A\example\project\target\scala-2.9.2\sbt-0.12\classes;C:\Docu
ments and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\net.databinder\dispatch-http_2.9.2\jars\disp
atch-http_2.9.2-0.8.8.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\net.databin
der\dispatch-core_2.9.2\jars\dispatch-core_2.9.2-0.8.8.jar;C:\Documents and Sett
ings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\jars\httpclient-4.1.3
.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpco
re\jars\httpcore-4.1.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\commons-lo
gging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\U
ser\.ivy2\cache\commons-codec\commons-codec\jars\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\Docume
nts and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\net.databinder\dispatch-futures_2.9.2\jars\dis
patch-futures_2.9.2-0.8.8.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.sca
lastyle\scalastyle_2.9.1\jars\scalastyle_2.9.1-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Documents a
nd Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scalariform\scalariform_2.9.1\jars\scalariform_
2.9.1-0.1.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\com.github.scopt\scop
t_2.9.1\jars\scopt_2.9.1-2.0.0.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\cc
.spray\spray-json_2.9.2\jars\spray-json_2.9.2-1.1.1.jar;C:\Documents and Setting
s\User\.ivy2\cache\org.parboiled\parboiled-scala\jars\parboiled-scala-1.0.2.jar;
C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.parboiled\parboiled-core\jars\par
boiled-core-1.0.2.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scalatest\s
calatest_2.9.2\jars\scalatest_2.9.2-1.9.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.iv
y2\cache\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\jars\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Document
s and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\com.typesafe.sbteclipse\sbt
eclipse-plugin\jars\sbteclipse-plugin-2.1.0.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.
ivy2\cache\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\com.typesafe.sbteclipse\sbteclipse-core\jars\sbt
eclipse-core-2.1.0.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scalaz\sca
laz-core_2.9.2\jars\scalaz-core_2.9.2-6.0.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.
ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\jars\sbt-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\
.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\main\jars\main-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Us
er\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\actions\jars\actions-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Se
ttings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\classpath\jars\classpath-0.12.4.jar;C:\Doc
uments and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\launcher-interface\jars\launc
her-interface-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sb
t\interface\jars\interface-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache
\org.scala-sbt\io\jars\io-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\
org.scala-sbt\control\jars\control-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.sb
t\boot\scala-2.9.2\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\c
ache\org.scala-sbt\completion\jars\completion-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settin
gs\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\collections\jars\collections-0.12.4.jar;C:\Doc
uments and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\jline\jline\jars\jline-1.0.jar;C:\Documents
 and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\api\jars\api-0.12.4.jar;C:\Document
s and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\compiler-integration\jars\compiler
-integration-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt
\incremental-compiler\jars\incremental-compiler-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Sett
ings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\logging\jars\logging-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents
 and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\process\jars\process-0.12.4.jar;C:\
Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\compile\jars\compile-0.12.
4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\persist\jars\pers
ist-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-tools.sbinar
y\sbinary_2.9.0\jars\sbinary_2.9.0-0.4.0.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy
2\cache\org.scala-sbt\classfile\jars\classfile-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Setti
ngs\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\compiler-ivy-integration\jars\compiler-ivy-in
tegration-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\iv
y\jars\ivy-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.ivy\
ivy\jars\ivy-2.3.0-rc1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\com.jcraft
\jsch\jars\jsch-0.1.46.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\commons-ht
tpclient\commons-httpclient\jars\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Documents and Set
tings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\run\jars\run-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Se
ttings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\task-system\jars\task-system-0.12.4.jar;C:
\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\tasks\jars\tasks-0.12.4.j
ar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\tracking\jars\tracki
ng-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\cache\jar
s\cache-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\test
ing\jars\testing-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala
-sbt\test-agent\jars\test-agent-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\
cache\org.scala-tools.testing\test-interface\jars\test-interface-0.5.jar;C:\Docu
ments and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\command\jars\command-0.12.4.ja
r;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\compiler-interface\ja
rs\compiler-interface-bin-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\
org.scala-sbt\compiler-interface\jars\compiler-interface-src-0.12.4.jar;C:\Docum
ents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\precompiled-2_8_2\jars\compiler
-interface-bin-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-s
bt\precompiled-2_9_3\jars\compiler-interface-bin-0.12.4.jar;C:\Documents and Set
tings\User\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\precompiled-2_10_1\jars\compiler-interface-
bin-0.12.4.jar
```

Comment: Are there any scala files lying around which contain classes named `Test`? That could be the reason. Possible places would be in the root folder of your project, in the `project` folder, or even somewhere else.

Comment: Even more likely this is a *java* class or source file lying around containing a class named `Test`

Comment: Also, try typing `l` at the error prompt and post the error log somewhere as it may give clues as to what's going on.

Comment: @jrudolph: I have updated my question, kindly view that.

Comment: What about a class named `Test`? Try going through all of the entries under `bootclasspath` and `classpath` which are directories and see if they contain a file ending with `Test.class` or a directory called `Test` or `test`.

Comment: Btw. I assume you already ensured that you really are working on a clean copy of the project. If not, make sure it is (= redownload, extract cleanly, and retry).

Comment: Yes, redownlaoded it, but kept getting the errors.

Comment: @jrudolph: There is a directory "test" in the src folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38398/discussion-between-jrudolph-and-eda)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pragmatic "solution" that may help to get you running for now: replace all those occurrences of `in Test` in `ProgFunBuild.scala` with `in sbt.Test` and then try again.

Still, something is broken in your environment.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, worked perfectly. I wish i could upvote your answer many times.

Comment: Really, glad we got this sorted out. Have fun with the course :)

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you run `sbt` is that it is not compiling *your sources* but the *build definition* of sbt. The problem seems to be that `Test` is not found. I can only vaguely speculate...

- Did you touch that file `ProgFunBuild` in any way?
- Did you accidentally place your normal source code in the `project` sub directory? Perhaps you did that and have an object `Test` defined in there which shadows sbt's `Test` scope?
- From what directory do you run sbt? You should be in the root folder of the example, *not inside the `project` directory*.

You should have the following layout:

```
project/ProgFunBuild.scala
project/build.properties    (optional)
build.sbt                   (optional)
src/main/scala/...          (your sources in there)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. For your first two queries, I didn't. Also, I am in the root folder, that is example folder. Also, my layout is same as you provided, just the build,sbt isn't there, but that is optional as you said.

Comment: Then I have no clue. So you are operating on the unmodified download from the ProgFun course? Perhaps try asking on the Coursera/ProgFun online forum.

Comment: I am one of the Community TAs for that course. There is definitely a build.sbt file at the root of the example project - I just downloaded and unzipped it, and it is there.

Comment: @DNA: Sorry, it is there. I had looked that in project folder by mistake..By the way, great to see a TA here, please take a look at here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38398/discussion-between-jrudolph-and-eda