# Scala build.sbt has unrecognized variables

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am doing the Scala course on Coursera. For one of the assignments, I have the following `build.sbt` file:

```
submitProjectName := "streams"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-unchecked",
  "-optimise",
  "-Yinline-warnings"
)

fork := true

javaOptions += "-Xmx2G"

parallelExecution in Test := false


// See documentation in ProgFunBuild.scala
projectDetailsMap := {
val currentCourseId = "progfun-006"
val depsQuickcheck = Seq(
    "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.1"
  )
Map(
  "example" ->  ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "example",
                  assignmentPartId = "gTzFogNk",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "recfun" ->     ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "recfun",
                  assignmentPartId = "4Rarn9Ki",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "funsets" ->    ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "funsets",
                  assignmentPartId = "gBXOL7Rd",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "objsets" ->    ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "objsets",
                  assignmentPartId = "25dMMEz7",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "patmat" ->     ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "patmat",
                  assignmentPartId = "6gPmpcif",
                  maxScore = 20d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "forcomp" ->    ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "forcomp",
                  assignmentPartId = "gG3oZGIO",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "streams" ->    ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "streams",
                  assignmentPartId = "1WKgCFCi",
                  maxScore = 20d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.2,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "quickcheck" -> ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "quickcheck",
                  assignmentPartId = "02Vi5q7m",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.0,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId,
                  dependencies=depsQuickcheck),
  "constraints"  -> ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "constraints",
                  assignmentPartId = "kL1K2FAj",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.0,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId),
  "interpreter"  -> ProjectDetails(
                  packageName = "interpreter",
                  assignmentPartId = "1SZhe1Ua283r87a7rd",
                  maxScore = 10d,
                  styleScoreRatio = 0.0,
                  styleSheet = (baseDirectory.value / "project" / "scalastyle_config.xml").toString,
                  courseId=currentCourseId)
)}

// Instrumentation
instrumentedClassPrefixes ++= Seq(
  "patmat",
  "forcomp"
)
```

I told it to resolve imports, however `submitProjectName`, `projectDetailsMap`, `instrumentedClassPrefixes` and everything within `Map` is still not recognized.

I am using Intellij.

Do you have any idea about what causes this?

**EDIT**

I reimported the project in Intellij and the errors disappeared.
I'm still confused about what was happening.

Comment: These settings might stem from a plug-in. Do you have a project that works? Then look what's in `project/plugins.sbt` or any other `.sbt` file in `project/`. You are probably missing that. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076952/why-are-the-compilation-errors-when-loading-scala-build-files) - you probably forgot to include `project/ProgFunBuild.scala`

Comment: I will then close the question if you don't mind

Comment: I am still curious about what was causing that, but close it if you want.

Comment: Hate repeating it, but: don't trust Intellij showing errors in Scala. It very often gets them wrong.